# javascript how to start for loop in index 6 and will end in index 3?

Tags: javascript, loops

```
--------------
|index |value|
|0     |a    |
|1     |b    |
|2     |c    |
|3     |d    |
|4     |e    |
|5     |f    |
|6     |g    |
|7     |h    |
--------------
```

I need to loop **in between** index 2 and 7. How could I achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far? Also could be a duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: You just need to write a simple `for`/`while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for ... loop` as in the code below:

```js
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];

// i = 2 for the starting index
//until you reach index 7
for (var i = 2; i <= 7; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
    //Do something
}
```

If you want to replace the **7** by the last case in your array you can do:

```js
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"];

// i = 2 for the starting index
//until you reach end of the array
for (var i = 2; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
    //Do something
}
```